# how to extract html code from webview

Tags: android, webview

this is my code ...... i cant resolve the error..

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.URI;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;

import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.webkit.WebView;

import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")

public class Social_media extends Fragment {
private String getDownloadButtonOnly(String url){

    URI http ;
    HttpGet pageGet = new HttpGet ( "http://visiblenews.com/category/gadgets/");


    ResponseHandler<String> handler = new ResponseHandler<String>() {
        public String handleResponse1(HttpResponse response) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String html; 

            if (entity != null) {
                html = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                return html;
            }else {
                return null;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public String handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
                throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

    };
    Object pageHTML = null;
    try {
        while (pageHTML==null){
            Object client;
            pageHTML = ((Object) client).execute(pageGet, handler);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<h2>Direct Down.+?</h2>(</div>)*(.+?)<.+?>", Pattern.DOTALL);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher((CharSequence) pageHTML);
        String displayHTML = null;
        while(matcher.find()){
            displayHTML = matcher.group();
        }

    return displayHTML;
}

    public void customizeWebView(final ServiceCommunicableActivity activity, final WebView webview, final SearchResult mRom) {
        mRom.setFileSize(getFileSize(mRom.getURLSuffix()));
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    }

    private Object getFileSize(Object urlSuffix) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }};
```

error log is ..

Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method execute(HttpGet, ResponseHandler) is undefined for the type Object   Social_media.java   /TabsWithSwipeGesture/src/info/androidhive/tabsswipe    line 62 Java Problem

Comment: please give me solution

Comment: You have this error at compile time? Or when running your app?

Comment: this error at compile time .

Comment: `Object` has no execute method.

Answer (score 0):

`Object` has no `execute()` method. You are supposed to use a `HttpClient` instance. Further I wonder what you want with pageHtml (and the loop there) as the html page will be availabel in `handleResponse'. Further the title of your post is strange as there is no WebView involved here.